# Google reCaptcha remove element

Tags: html, css, contact-form-7, recaptcha

So I have installed Google reCaptcha for my site and everything is fine expect from the fact it won't allow me to align it in the center on my page, the only reason I can see is by default it is giving a div element the width of 304px.

When I remove this using Google Developer Tool and then give the div element text-align center it aligns the reCaptcha in the center of my page but the div that is doing all this has no class that I can override and I can't edit the div as it's build into the reCaptcha.

Any ideas?

I'm grateful for any help

Thank you,
Ste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
.g-recaptcha > div > div{ margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
.g-recaptcha{
  margin: 15px auto !important;
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  text-align: -moz-center;
  text-align: -o-center;
  text-align: -ms-center;
}
```

It worked for me.